# Is return traffic for SSL-enabled HAProxy secured also?

Tags: ssl, haproxy

I've got a HAProxy in front of a number of Webservers. Connection from clients to HAProxy is SSL secured. But it is terminated at HAProxy and traffic from HAProxy to the underlying Webservers are in clear.

I am clear about how the forward traffic goes, ie, from Client >> HAProxy >> Webservers. But what about the reversed? From Webserver to Client? Is it secured as well?

Comment: Did you mean the server response? Yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the server response is returned through the same communication channel, plain HTTP (webserver -> haproxy) and HTTPS (haproxy -> client).

Comment: Thanks for verification! I initially thought webserver will just communicate directly to client, skipping haproxy thereafter.

Comment: Can I also ask if this is also the behaviour for AWS ELB? =)

Comment: Yes, ELB is/uses HAProxy. But this behavior is from the server-client model.